# jQuery [Object object] Error

Tags: jquery

```
$('td').click(function () {
    var total = $('<div id="total"></div>')
    var price = +($(this).text())
    var old = +($('#total').text())
    var newPrice = (old + price)
    $('<div class="notice"></div>')
        .append('<div class="skin"></div>')
        .append($('<div class="content"></div>').text('Total price:' + " " + $('#total').text(newPrice)))
        .hide()
        .appendTo('#panel_two')
        .fadeIn(1000);
    $('#panel_two').fadeIn().appendTo('#windowContainer');
}
```

I get object Object error in line where I'm trying to display my newPrice (Total price:) Any ideas?

However this works fine:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('td').click(function(){
    var Price = +($(this).text());
    var Old = +($('#Total').text());
    var New = (Old + Price);
    $('#Total').text(New);
   })
})
```

Comment: please format the code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Also post your html for it

Comment: Your code is all kinds of wrong...

Comment: `[Object object]` is technically not an error message. It's how objects cast to string.

Comment: `newPrice` doesn't appear it should contain `"[Object object]"`. It's a sum of two numbers. `NaN`, at worst.

Comment: `parseInt` is your friend.

Comment: `$('#total').text(newPrice)` is _not_ anywhere close to being worthy of a cast to string. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
$('td').click(function()
{
    var Price = +($(this).text());
    var Old = +($('#Total').text());
    var New = (Old + Price);
    $('#Total').text(New);
})
})  I sorry just need to learn how to format text in here properly, however this code works.

Comment: Your operator seems incorrect. It should be `=+` instead of `= +`

Comment: @VincentBowman please edit the question if you want to add code. It's unreadable as a comment.

Comment: @Derek there's nothing wrong with `= +`. `=+` might be confused with `+=`, on the other hand.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak Thanks, just recognized that is `+=` lol

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<div class="content"></div>')
   .text('Total price:' + " " + $('#total').text(newPrice) )
```

basically means "find `#total`, set its text to the value of `newPrice`, concatenate the return value of `.text(...)` with `"Total price: "`, and set that as the text of the new element".

Now, the return value of `$('#total').text(newPrice)` is `$('#total')`, not `newPrice`. That is, nothing worthy of being converted to a string for concatenation.

Perhaps this is what you want?:

```
$('#total').text(newPrice);
$('<div class="content"></div>').text('Total price:' + " " + newPrice)
//...
```

Comment: Now it says total = 0. The second block does what I want but for some reason it does't work with my second version (first block of code).

Comment: @VincentBowman if `this` and `#total` are inputs, use `.value()` to read their values

Comment: @VincentBowman also, if the text of `#total` isn't a number (and not empty), the unary plus will yield a `NaN`.

Comment: #total is just an empty div element. I use it to display my newPrice variable.

Comment: this refers to td element which has a text value, so it's not empty.

Comment: is the text value a number?